# Django Rest JWT login using username or email?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using **django-rest-jwt** for authentication in my app.

By default it user username field to autenticate a user but I want let the users login using **email or username**.

Is there any mean supported by django-rest-jwt to accomplish this.
I know the last option would be write my own login method.

Answer (score 30):

No need to write a custom authentication backend or custom login method.

A Custom Serializer inheriting JSONWebTokenSerializer, renaming the 'username_field' and overriding def validate() method.

This works perfectly for 'username_or_email' and 'password' fields where the user can enter its username or email and get the JSONWebToken for correct credentials.

```
from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import JSONWebTokenSerializer

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from rest_framework import serializers

from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings


User = get_user_model()
jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
jwt_decode_handler = api_settings.JWT_DECODE_HANDLER
jwt_get_username_from_payload = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER

class CustomJWTSerializer(JSONWebTokenSerializer):
    username_field = 'username_or_email'

    def validate(self, attrs):

        password = attrs.get("password")
        user_obj = User.objects.filter(email=attrs.get("username_or_email")).first() or User.objects.filter(username=attrs.get("username_or_email")).first()
        if user_obj is not None:
            credentials = {
                'username':user_obj.username,
                'password': password
            }
            if all(credentials.values()):
                user = authenticate(**credentials)
                if user:
                    if not user.is_active:
                        msg = _('User account is disabled.')
                        raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

                    payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)

                    return {
                        'token': jwt_encode_handler(payload),
                        'user': user
                    }
                else:
                    msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

            else:
                msg = _('Must include "{username_field}" and "password".')
                msg = msg.format(username_field=self.username_field)
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

        else:
            msg = _('Account with this email/username does not exists')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
```

In urls.py:

```
url(r'{Your url name}$', ObtainJSONWebToken.as_view(serializer_class=CustomJWTSerializer)),
```

Answer (score 13):

Building on top of Shikhar's answer and for anyone coming here looking for a solution for **rest_framework_simplejwt** (since **django-rest-framework-jwt** seems to be dead, it's last commit was 2 years ago) like me, here's a general solution that tries to alter as little as possible the original validation from `TokenObtainPairSerializer`:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class CustomJWTSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        credentials = {
            'username': '',
            'password': attrs.get("password")
        }

        # This is answering the original question, but do whatever you need here. 
        # For example in my case I had to check a different model that stores more user info
        # But in the end, you should obtain the username to continue.
        user_obj = User.objects.filter(email=attrs.get("username")).first() or User.objects.filter(username=attrs.get("username")).first()
        if user_obj:
            credentials['username'] = user_obj.username

        return super().validate(credentials)
```

And in urls.py:

`url(r'^token/$', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(serializer_class=CustomJWTSerializer)),`

Comment: Thanks, this made me realize that **django-rest-framework-jwt** is no longer maintained, which is critical!

Comment: I changed `username` in the code to `email` and I could use the `email` field during login.  
I also had to set `username_field = 'email'` as a class variable.

Answer (score 1):

Found out a workaround.

```
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def signin_jwt_wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
    request_data = request.data
    host = request.get_host()
    username_or_email = request_data['username']
    if isEmail(username_or_email):
        # get the username for this email by model lookup
        username = Profile.get_username_from_email(username_or_email)
        if username is None:
            response_text = {"non_field_errors":["Unable to login with provided credentials."]}
            return JSONResponse(response_text, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        username = username_or_email

    data = {'username': username, 'password':request_data['password']}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    url = 'http://' + host + '/user/signin_jwt/'
    response = requests.post(url,data=dumps(data), headers=headers)

    return JSONResponse(loads(response.text), status=response.status_code)
```

I check that whether the text that I received is a username or an email.

If email then I lookup the username for that and then just pass that to `/signin_jwt/`

Answer (score 1):

authentication.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomAuthBackend(object):
    """
    This class does the athentication-
    using the user's email address.
    """
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

settings.py

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'app_name.authentication.CustomAuthBackend',
]
```

---

**How it works:**

If user try to authenticate using their username django will look at the `ModelBackend` class. However, if the user adds its email instead, django will try `ModelBackend` but will not find the logic needed, then will try the `CustomAuthBackend` class making it work the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this new DRF Auth project [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth) seems to provide support for log in by username or email through [djangorestframework-simplejwt](https://github.com/jazzband/django-rest-framework-simplejwt).

Answer (score 0):

1. dj-rest-auth works better for authentication and authorization. By default dj-rest-auth provides - username, email and password fields for login. User can provide email and password or username and password. Token will be generated, if the provided values are valid.
2. If you need to edit these login form, extend LoginSerializer and modify fields. Later make sure to add new custom serializer to settings.py.

   REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
   'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'yourapp.customlogin_serializers.CustomLoginSerializer'
   }
3. Configuring dj-rest-auth is bit tricky, since it has an open issue related to the refresh token pending. There is workaround suggested for that issue, so you can follow below links and have it configured.

https://medium.com/geekculture/jwt-authentication-in-django-part-1-implementing-the-backend-b7c58ab9431b

https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/97

Answer (score 0):

If you use the rest_framework_simplejwt this is a simple mode. views.py

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import generics

class EmailAuthToken(generics.GenericAPIView):
 def post(self, request):

    user_data = request.data
    try:
        user = authenticate(request, username=user_data['username_or_email'], password=user_data['password'])
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)

            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

            return JsonResponse({
                'refresh': str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token),
            }, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({
                    "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
                }, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except:
            return Response({'error': 'The format of the information is not valid'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```