# How JWT works with django-phonenumber-field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-auth

I have used [django-phonenumber-field](https://pypi.org/project/django-phonenumber-field/) as my Phone number model field and serializer. It worked and everything was okay. Now, I am trying to implement Json Web Token in Django Rest Framework of these two package, **djsoer** and **djangorestframework-jwt**. I am managing and migrating an old (django 1.11) codebase to Django2. Right now, whenever I am trying to create a new auth token, I am getting an internal server error. 
Error message:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'PhoneNumber' is not JSON serializable
```

I know PhoneNumber object from Django-phonenumber-field package is responsible for this. However, The error stack is in **djangorestframework-jwt**. How can I add/pass PhoneNumber serializer on JWT?

[ I don't get which codebase is necessary, so I have not added any. Ask me, I will describe/add later.]

TIA.

**Edit #1:**

Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /api/auth/create_token/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
     response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
   File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
   File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework_jwt/views.py", line 57, in post
     if serializer.is_valid():
   File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 236, in is_valid
     self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
   File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 437, in run_validation
     value = self.validate(value)
   File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework_jwt/serializers.py", line 60, in validate
     'token': jwt_encode_handler(payload),
   File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework_jwt/utils.py", line 95, in jwt_encode_handler
     api_settings.JWT_ALGORITHM
  File "/home/a_o/.local/share/virtualenvs/conveyanceappbackend-Y2Y7Ynbu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 62, in encode
    cls=json_encoder
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
     return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
o.__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: Please share the traceback, so that we can take a better look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Added @SurajThapar

Comment: check this answer maybe helps you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332074/django-rest-jwt-login-using-username-or-email/46191939#46191939

Comment: Related : Django 2 + djangorestframework-jwt https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/433#issuecomment-390478184 (edited)

Comment: Try overwriting : `def jwt_encode_handler(payload):` and In your `settings.py`, add `JWT_AUTH = { 'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER': 'your_app.utils.jwt_encode_handler', }` (Ref : https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/utils.py#L90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to JWT. Rest Framework is trying to serialize the Phonenumber field to json, but it doesn't know how to do that. Take a look at the DRF docs for how to implement [a custom field](http://%20https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) -- the field is responsible for knowing how to convert between the initial data-type and a serialized representation, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out later. And then changed my model to CharField from PhoneNumberField and validate phone number in another custom method using the serializer (PhoneNumberField)